# null object is returned while getting fragment from another activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to set text to TextView in myfragment.xml from mainactivity.java
but following error occurs.

This is my main_activity.java

```
@Override                                                                                   
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {                                          

    if(aBoolean){                                                                           
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);       
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                                       
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                      
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.top_to_bottom, R.anim.bottom_to_top);
        dropdown dropdown = new dropdown();                                                 
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,dropdown);                          
        fragmentTransaction.commit();                                                       
        dropdown.setTextView("Heading1","HelloWorld");                                      
        aBoolean=false;                                                                     

    }                                                                                       

    else {                                                                                  
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                      
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
        dropdown dropdown = new dropdown();                                                 

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,dropdown);                          
        fragmentTransaction.commit();                                                       
        dropdown.setTextView("Heading1","HelloWorld");                                      
    }
```

I write a method for settext in fragment file

dropdown.java

```
public class dropdown extends Fragment {
    View main_view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dropdown, container, false);
        main_view = v;
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.heading1);
        textView.setText("hello");
        return v;
    }

    public void setTextView(String id, String text){
        TextView textView = (TextView) main_view.findViewById(R.id.heading1);
        textView.setText("HelloWorld");
    }

}
```

following error occur at runtime

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.app.Fragment.getId()' on a null object reference
```

this error shows in a line at dropdown.setTextView("Heading1","HelloWorld");

Comment: is the fragment is under mainActivity ?

Comment: @Alex Chengalan no it is an another xml file

Answer (score 0):

Code is not sufficient. But let me guess the problem..
I think your Fragment is in `android.app` package and you are calling by `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: No changing into android.supprt.v4.app.Fragment doesn't work. The same error appears

Comment: 'dropdown dropdown = new dropdown();'          I think it is a so confusing and strange design

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do it this way.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("KEY_STRING", "HELLOWORLD");
                fragmentTransaction.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then from Fragment Class

```
    String Helloworld =  getArguments().getString("KEY_STRING");
textView.setText(Helloworld);
```

Comment: error `cannot resolve method setArguments`. And I checked in android developers.com i haven't find this method in there either.

Comment: Try to change this line
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

See if that would help

Comment: now it shows error at line `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,dropdown);` cannot resolve method add

Comment: use .replace instead of .add
then add this line .addToBackStack(null); before commit code.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the mistake in there, every time i enter the text in search view new dropdown is object is created. This is why i get null object reference.  So declared that as final variable. solve the question.

```
@Override                                                                                           
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                             
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                         

    final dropdown dropdown = new dropdown();                                                       

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById (R.id.search_view);                                      
    searchView.setQueryHint("search");                                                              

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {                        
        @Override                                                                                   
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {                                            
            return false;                                                                           
        }                                                                                           

        @Override                                                                                   
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {                                          

            if(aBoolean){                                                                           
                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);       
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                                       
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                      
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.top_to_bottom, R.anim.bottom_to_top);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,dropdown);                      
                fragmentTransaction.commit();                                                       
                aBoolean=false;                                                                     
            }                                                                                       

            else{                                                                                   

                 dropdown.setTextView(R.id.heading1,"Heading1");                                    
            }                                                                                       
            return false;                                                                           
        }                                                                                           
    });}
```